# Json Data not showing in CollectionView in .NET MAUI

Tags: c#, json, maui

I am working on building a hymn app in .Net MAUI. I am relatively new to the framework. I am trying to populate a CollectionView in my MainPage with a list of hymn titles from a JSON file in my Resources/Raw/ folder. But whenever I run the app nothing shows up. I am getting kinda frustrated. Please can anyone be of assistance?

**Here is the JSON file called tac_hymn_latest.json**

```
{
  "number": 282,
  "title": "Awurade Nyankopɔn",
  "favorite_flag": false,
  "verse1": "Awurade Nyankopɔn\nƆsεefo no aba\nWo bobe turo mu\nResεe wo nsa ano nnwuma\n\n(Chorus)\nMa wo nsa so, ma wo nsa so\nAsafo Yehowa;\nMa wo bɔhyε Kronkron gya no\nMmεhyew ne nnwuma nyinaa",
  "verse2": "Awurade Nyankopɔn\nBεtɔ anɔpa nsu\nGu wo bobe turo mu\nNa ne nyinaa nyε frɔmfrɔm",
  "verse3": "Awurade Nyankopɔn\nYεn ani da wo so;\nYehia wo, Awurade, Kristo\nBεbɔ w’asafo hyew",
  "verse4": "Awurade Nyankopɔn\nWo mmere no awie du;\nEnti ma nsεnkyerεne\nNna adi w’asafo mu",
  "verse5": "Awurade Nyankopɔn\nGyedifo Nyankopɔn,\nYεretwεn w’asεm no,\nMa ɔhyewbɔ no mmra",
  "verse6": "Awurade Nyankopɔn\nSoma nsεmpakafo\nKɔ wiase sum yi mu\nNkɔbɔ nkwagye dawuru"
},
{
  "number": 283,
  "title": "Ma Onyankopɔn nsɔre n’atamfo so",
  "favorite_flag": false,
  "verse1": "Ma Onyankopɔn nsɔre n’atamfo so\nNa ma wɔn a wokyi no nguan n’anim\nFa w’anom mframa no bɔ\nW’atamfo no hwete,\nNa yebehyira wo",
  "verse2": "Ma treneefo anigye wɔ wo mmoa ho,\nBεhwε wɔn hia na wɔbehyiara wo;\nWo nsam na nnepa wɔ, enti behu yεn mmɔbɔ\nNa yebehyira wo",
  "verse3": "Wo na wofi dii wo man anim no\nSoro ne asase wosoe wɔ wɔn anim\nIsraεl Nyankopɔn ma wo nkorɔfo nhu wog ye\nNa yebehyira wo",
  "verse4": "Bεto adom nsu gu wagyade so,\nOnyankopɔn ma ensi yεn yiye;\nKasa ma wo nkorɔfo, bεhwε amanehunufo\nNa yebehyira wo",
  "verse5": "Ma wo tumi basa no nna adi nnε,\nMa ɔtamfo dɔm no nguan wɔ w’anim,\nOtumfo sɔre bra, begye wɔn a wɔfrε wo,\nNa yebehyira wo",
  "verse6": "Wo ne ahohia mu baofo pa koro no\nWo nsam na tumi a egye nkwa wɔ,\nWo na yεbɔ wo mpae, pae aprana gu wɔn so,\nNa yebehyira wo",
  "verse7": "Onyankopɔn na yεkoto sɔre no,\nW’ahyεde nso di tumi ma wo,\nNhyira ne Awurade, wosoa yεn adesoa nti\nMomma yεnhyira no"
},
{
  "number": 284,
  "title": "Onyankopɔn gye me kra",
  "favorite_flag": false,
  "verse1": "Onyankopɔn gye me kra,\nFa sie dabi m’ahu wo;\nMe kra retwεn w’asεm so,\nNa mate won ne dasum’",
  "verse2": "Onyankopɔn hwε so,\nBɔ me ho ban matamfo nti;\nKyerε me w’akwan trenee,\nNa mate won ne dasum’",
  "verse3": "Onyankopɔn gye me fi\nAtεkyε dontori mu;\nFa hisop horo me ho,\nNa mate won ne dasum’",
  "verse4": "Onyankopɔn fa me sie\nW’asεm kronkron no mu daa;\nBoa me na menyε wo pε,\nNa mate won ne dasum’",
  "verse5": "Onyankopɔn ne me boafo,\nMe mmrεwyε mu ɔbεboa me;\nObetumi aboa me\nNa mate won ne dasum’",
  "verse6": "Onyankopɔn nkutoo na\nMe kra ani da no so;\nEnti εbεhyε me den,\nNa mate won ne dasum’"
}
```

Here is my HymnModel.cs in the Models folder

```
namespace HymnApp.Models
{
    public class HymnModel
    {
            public int number { get; set; }
            public string title { get; set; }
            public bool favorite_flag { get; set; }
            public string? verse1 { get; set; }
            public string? verse2 { get; set; }
            public string? verse3 { get; set; }
            public string? verse4 { get; set; }
            public string? verse5 { get; set; }
            public string? verse6 { get; set; }
            public string? verse7 { get; set; }
            public string? verse8 { get; set; }
            public string? verse9 { get; set; }
            public string? verse10 { get; set; }

    }
}
```

**Here is the HymnService.cs located in the Services folder**

```
using HymnApp.Models;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace HymnApp.Services
{
    public class HymnService
    {
        List<HymnModel> hymnList;

        public async Task<List<HymnModel>> GetHymns()
        {
            if (hymnList?.Count > 0)
                return hymnList;

            var jsonPath = "tac_hymn_latest.json";
            var contents = File.ReadAllText(jsonPath);
            hymnList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<HymnModel>>(contents);

            return hymnList;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the MainViewModel.cs in the ViewModels folder

```
using HymnApp.Models;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using HymnApp.Services;

namespace HymnApp.ViewModels;

public partial class MainViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    public ObservableCollection<HymnModel> Hymns { get; } = new();
    
    HymnService hymnService;

    [ObservableProperty]
    public string title = "Hymn APP";
    
    public MainViewModel(HymnService hymnService) 
    { 
        this.hymnService = hymnService;
        GetHymnsAsync();
    }

    [RelayCommand]
    async Task GetHymnsAsync()
    {
        try
        {
            var hymns = await hymnService.GetHymns();
        
            if (Hymns.Count != 0)
                Hymns.Clear();

            foreach (var hymn in hymns)
            {
                Hymns.Add(hymn);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine($"Unable to get hymns: {ex.Message}");
            await Shell.Current.DisplayAlert("Error!", ex.Message, "OK");
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the MainPage.xaml located in the Views folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage
    x:Class="HymnApp.Views.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:model="clr-namespace:HymnApp.Models"
    xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:HymnApp.ViewModels"
    Title="{Binding Title}"
    x:DataType="vm:MainViewModel">


    <CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding Hymns}">
        <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="model:HymnModel">
                <Frame>
                    <HorizontalStackLayout>
                        <Label Text="{Binding title}" />
                        <Label Text="{Binding verse1}" />
                    </HorizontalStackLayout>
                </Frame>
            </DataTemplate>
        </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
    </CollectionView>
</ContentPage>
```

```
Here is the MainPage.xaml.cs


namespace HymnApp.Views;
using HymnApp.ViewModels;

public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public MainPage(MainViewModel mainViewModel)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        

        BindingContext = mainViewModel;
    }
}
```

here is my GlobalUsings.cs file

```
global using CommunityToolkit.Maui;
global using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.ComponentModel;
global using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.Input;
global using HymnApp.ViewModels;
global using HymnApp.Views;
global using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
global using System.ComponentModel;
global using System.Diagnostics;
global using System.Globalization;
global using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
global using System.Text.Json;
global using System.Threading.Tasks;
```

Here is the MauiProgram.cs

```
using HymnApp.Services;

namespace HymnApp;

public static class MauiProgram
{
    public static MauiApp CreateMauiApp()
    {
        var builder = MauiApp.CreateBuilder();
        builder
            .UseMauiApp<App>()
            .UseMauiCommunityToolkit()
            .ConfigureFonts(fonts =>
            {
                fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Regular.ttf", "OpenSansRegular");
                fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Semibold.ttf", "OpenSansSemibold");
            });

        builder.Services.AddSingleton<MainViewModel>();

        builder.Services.AddSingleton<MainPage>();
        builder.Services.AddSingleton<HymnService>();

        return builder.Build();
    }
}
```

The rest of the App, such as the App.xaml and AppShell.xaml are the defaults for some reason my data is not being populated in the app.

I've tried running the App multiple times, restoring nuget packages and even rebuilding it in a different project, but nothing seems to work.

Comment: Use the [file system helpers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/storage/file-system-helpers?view=net-maui-8.0&tabs=android#bundled-files) to read bundled files

Comment: Do you see in your ViewModel that the collection is building correctly while debugging?

Comment: Yes. The CollectionView works alright when I test with some dummy texts. The content of the json file just fails to populate it. However, thanks for your response.

Comment: @Jason thanks for info, it was very informative. I will try it out and see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `FileSystem.OpenAppPackageFileAsync(jsonPath)` to read the json file.

Based on your code, I created a demo and achieved this function on my side.

You can refer to the following code:

```
internal class HymnService
    {
        List<HymnModel> hymnList;

        public async Task<List<HymnModel>> GetHymns()
        {
            if (hymnList?.Count > 0)
                return hymnList;

            try {
                string jsonPath = "tac_hymn_latest.json";
                 
               // read json file here
                using var stream = await FileSystem.OpenAppPackageFileAsync(jsonPath);
                using var reader = new StreamReader(stream);

               string jsonstr = reader.ReadToEnd();
               hymnList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<HymnModel>>(jsonstr);
            }
            catch {
           
           
            }

            return hymnList;
        }

    }
```

Besides,the format of the Json file is not correct, please add `[]` outside of it.

```
[
  {
    "number": 282,
    "title": "Awurade Nyankopɔn",
    "favorite_flag": false,
    "verse1": "Awurade Nyankopɔn\nƆsεefo no aba\nWo bobe turo mu\nResεe wo nsa ano nnwuma\n\n(Chorus)\nMa wo nsa so, ma wo nsa so\nAsafo Yehowa;\nMa wo bɔhyε Kronkron gya no\nMmεhyew ne nnwuma nyinaa",
    "verse2": "Awurade Nyankopɔn\nBεtɔ anɔpa nsu\nGu wo bobe turo mu\nNa ne nyinaa nyε frɔmfrɔm",
    "verse3": "Awurade Nyankopɔn\nYεn ani da wo so;\nYehia wo, Awurade, Kristo\nBεbɔ w’asafo hyew",
    "verse4": "Awurade Nyankopɔn\nWo mmere no awie du;\nEnti ma nsεnkyerεne\nNna adi w’asafo mu",
    "verse5": "Awurade Nyankopɔn\nGyedifo Nyankopɔn,\nYεretwεn w’asεm no,\nMa ɔhyewbɔ no mmra",
    "verse6": "Awurade Nyankopɔn\nSoma nsεmpakafo\nKɔ wiase sum yi mu\nNkɔbɔ nkwagye dawuru"
  },
  {
    "number": 283,
    "title": "Ma Onyankopɔn nsɔre n’atamfo so",
    "favorite_flag": false,
    "verse1": "Ma Onyankopɔn nsɔre n’atamfo so\nNa ma wɔn a wokyi no nguan n’anim\nFa w’anom mframa no bɔ\nW’atamfo no hwete,\nNa yebehyira wo",
    "verse2": "Ma treneefo anigye wɔ wo mmoa ho,\nBεhwε wɔn hia na wɔbehyiara wo;\nWo nsam na nnepa wɔ, enti behu yεn mmɔbɔ\nNa yebehyira wo",
    "verse3": "Wo na wofi dii wo man anim no\nSoro ne asase wosoe wɔ wɔn anim\nIsraεl Nyankopɔn ma wo nkorɔfo nhu wog ye\nNa yebehyira wo",
    "verse4": "Bεto adom nsu gu wagyade so,\nOnyankopɔn ma ensi yεn yiye;\nKasa ma wo nkorɔfo, bεhwε amanehunufo\nNa yebehyira wo",
    "verse5": "Ma wo tumi basa no nna adi nnε,\nMa ɔtamfo dɔm no nguan wɔ w’anim,\nOtumfo sɔre bra, begye wɔn a wɔfrε wo,\nNa yebehyira wo",
    "verse6": "Wo ne ahohia mu baofo pa koro no\nWo nsam na tumi a egye nkwa wɔ,\nWo na yεbɔ wo mpae, pae aprana gu wɔn so,\nNa yebehyira wo",
    "verse7": "Onyankopɔn na yεkoto sɔre no,\nW’ahyεde nso di tumi ma wo,\nNhyira ne Awurade, wosoa yεn adesoa nti\nMomma yεnhyira no"
  },
  {
    "number": 284,
    "title": "Onyankopɔn gye me kra",
    "favorite_flag": false,
    "verse1": "Onyankopɔn gye me kra,\nFa sie dabi m’ahu wo;\nMe kra retwεn w’asεm so,\nNa mate won ne dasum’",
    "verse2": "Onyankopɔn hwε so,\nBɔ me ho ban matamfo nti;\nKyerε me w’akwan trenee,\nNa mate won ne dasum’",
    "verse3": "Onyankopɔn gye me fi\nAtεkyε dontori mu;\nFa hisop horo me ho,\nNa mate won ne dasum’",
    "verse4": "Onyankopɔn fa me sie\nW’asεm kronkron no mu daa;\nBoa me na menyε wo pε,\nNa mate won ne dasum’",
    "verse5": "Onyankopɔn ne me boafo,\nMe mmrεwyε mu ɔbεboa me;\nObetumi aboa me\nNa mate won ne dasum’",
    "verse6": "Onyankopɔn nkutoo na\nMe kra ani da no so;\nEnti εbεhyε me den,\nNa mate won ne dasum’"
  }
]
```

**Note:**

1.Please set the build action of file `tac_hymn_latest.json`  to `MauiAsset`.

2.For more information,please check document: [File system helpers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/storage/file-system-helpers?view=net-maui-8.0&tabs=android).

Comment: Sorry, was offline for a while. @Jessie, Thank you very much. Your solution worked perfectly. It is running very smoothly. My only problem is I'm having problem navigating to a details page when an item is selected from the collectionview. Upon clicking on an item, a "System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object." I've watched various videos on YouTube, but each method returns the same error.

Comment: Hi @MaxwellKwashie, one problem, one thread.  For the new thread, you can create a new thread for it. We are all willing to help you. :)